# What are the closed subsets of a collection of all subsets of $\Bbb N$ (the set of all natural numbers)

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Can someone help me on this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you how closed sets are defined in a topological space?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but since all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is open, aren't all subsets closed?

Comment: If $F\subset\mathbb{N}$ then $U=\mathbb{N}\setminus F$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $U$ is open. It follows that $F$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks @OscarRascal....I got it now

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a subset of $ \mathbb N$. Then $\mathbb N \setminus A$ is open, hence $A$ is closed.

Comment: Yeah, its a good explanation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The topology $\tau_a$ is the *discrete topology*.  Every subset is open, therefore the complement of every subset is open, therefore every subset is closed.

Comment: So true, got it. Thanks a lot.